# Multicolumn in Latex

Tags: latex

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, but I just can´t figure out how to create this table, while keeping it somewhat nice looking.

I have attached an image, containing an Excel representation of the table I'm trying to create.

[image: Table]

I hope a Latex master can help me out here!

Comment: Have a look at the `booktabs` package manual about examples of nice and professional looking tables. Please do your readers a favour and don't attempt to build such data-prison-style tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\multicolumn{n-cells}{alignment}{content}`

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   Outer Fold   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ANN model} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Lin Reg model} & Baseline model \\
   \hline
   i    & $h_i^*$ & $E_i^{test}$ & $L_i^*$ & $E_i^{test}$ & $E_i^{test}$ \\
   \hline
   1 & 3 & 0.301 & 128 & 1.206 & 1.219 \\
   1 & 3 & 0.301 & 128 & 1.206 & 1.219 \\
   1 & 3 & 0.301 & 128 & 1.206 & 1.219 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: MWE]